# Eclipse doesn't recognize anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, eclipse, class, ide

For some reason, Eclipse does not seem to recognize when anonymous inner classes are used and prints an error message that the anonymous class in question does not exist. After trying to run the following example, which is copied directly from the book Thinking in Java, I get `Contents cannot be resolved to a type`

```
public class Parcel7 {
    public Contents contents() {
        return new Contents() { // Insert a class definition
            private int i = 11;

            public int value() {
                return i;
            }
        }; // Semicolon required in this case
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parcel7 p = new Parcel7();
        Contents c = p.contents();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You haven't imported (or maybe even created) `Contents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be an **class** or **interface** called Contents for this to work, are you sure that it has been created or imported?

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept answers on your questions. Good luck with your programming!:)